# How to get result from aggregate mongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection like following:

```
{  "_id" : ObjectId("5716617f4af77ca97a9614bd"), "flag": { "status": true, "userId": ObjectId"606b0e9f00bece43471baa50")}, "text" : "Main Comment 1", "reply" : [ { "_id" : ObjectId("571661cd4af77ca97a9614c1"), "flag": { "status": true }, "text" : "Main Comment 1 reply 1" }, { "_id" : ObjectId("571661cd4af77ca97a9614c2"), "flag": { "status": true, "userId": ObjectId("606b0e9f00bece43471baa48")}, "text" : "Main Comment 1 reply 2" } ] }
```

Expected result is,

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5716617f4af77ca97a9614bd"), "text" : "Main Comment 1",  reply: { } }

{ "_id" : ObjectId("5716617f4af77ca97a9614bd"), "text" : "Main Comment 1", reply: { "_id" : ObjectId("571661cd4af77ca97a9614c2"), "text" : "Main Comment 1 reply 1" } }

{ "_id" : ObjectId("5716617f4af77ca97a9614bd"), "text" : "Main Comment 1", reply: { "_id" : ObjectId("571661cd4af77ca97a9614c2"), "text" : "Main Comment 1 reply 2" } }
```

This is my Query which I am using:

```
db.comments.aggregate([
{ $unwind: { path: "$reply", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true } },
{ $match: { $or: [ { 'flag.status': true }, { 'reply.flag.status': true }]} },
])
```

By using this code, I am not getting the expected result.
Please let me know what to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `$match` put your match stage first
- `$unwind` deconstruct `reply` array
- `$project` to show required fields and check condition for `reply` if `flag` match than return `reply` otherwise empty object

```
db.comments.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $or: [
        { "flag.status": true },
        { "reply.flag.status": true }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$reply",
      preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 1,
      text: 1,
      reply: {
        $cond: [
          { $eq: ["$reply.flag.status", true] },
          {
            _id: "$reply._id",
            text: "$reply.text"
          },
          {}
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/b179XKT6zwN)

Comment: Not working as per my requirement, If comment collection `flag.status` will be `true` &  `reply.flag.status` will be `false` at that time getting duplicate value.

I have updated question so you can get better view.

Comment: actually you have added the condition one of them should be true in $match, can you explain your $match condition or requirement please.

Comment: I have `comments` collection with `reply` filed with array. 

If userA comments & userB reply on that. After that, UserC flag the comment of userA. At that time, data of userA should display only

Comment: this kind of operation is not valid transaction in mongodb,  i would suggest you to redesign your schema structure as per requirement of fields and conditions.